# How to efficiently validate collection of Ids against a database or any external data source?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a service that takes as a parameter ProcessOrdersArgs which can contain thousands of Order objects. I need to validate against a database server that each order passed in is an actual valid order that exists.  Right now for a single service call that is processing thousands of orders, I'm making thousands of round trips to the database just to validate the passed in orders and I would like to significantly reduce the number of database round trips for validation.

I have the following relevant classes for my validations. .CustomerId and .OrderId in my OrderValidator are extensions to FluentValidation PropertyValidator class.

CustomerIdValidator has caching built in because often of the thousands of orders being processed, many are for the same customer and I want to cut round trips to the database in validating the same CustomerId.

I would like to do something similar with OrderIds and limit the number of data base roundtrips, but caching is not the solution since each OrderId of the possible thousands will be unique.  I would like to validate these OrderIds in bulk.  My idea is to bulk copy the list of OrderIds for each client and return a list of invalid OrderIds (if any) to report as validation errors.

How do I do this, or is there another way I need to structure my validations so I can validate orders in bulk instead of making thousands of round trip database calls?

```
public class Order
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessOrdersArgs
{
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessOrdersArgsValidator : AbstractValidator<ProcessOrdersArgs>
{
    public ProcessOrdersArgsValidator(OrderValidator orderValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Orders)
            .SetCollectionValidator(orderValidator);
    }
}

public class OrderValidator : AbstractValidator<Order>
{
    public OrderValidator(DBConnection dbConnection)
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.CustomerId)
            .CustomerId(dbConnection);

        RuleFor(c => c.OrderId)
            .OrderId(dbConnection, c => c.CustomerId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider inserting the data into the database? You could create a table with one column and a foreign key referencing the actual IDs stored in the database. If the insert fails, there is an invalid ID in your data set.

Comment: I know many ways to validate a list of Ids, in bulk, against a database. That isn't the point of my question. I want to understand how to do this with Fluent Validation. My issue is my OrderId property validator has a DB connection and has to validate each OrderId individually.  I feel like I need to push this validation up to the ProcessOrdersArgsValidator itself and do the validation in bulk there, maybe using a method similar to what you are suggesting or something else. Against, I am just not sure how this should look with Fluent Validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [predicate validator](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/c.-Built-In-Validators#predicate-validator) `Must` or `MustAsync` for `Orders` property

```
public class ProcessOrdersArgsValidator : AbstractValidator<ProcessOrdersArgs>
{
    public ProcessOrdersArgsValidator(DBConnection dbConnection)
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Orders).Must(orders =>
        {
            var ids = orders.Select(o => o.OrderId);

            return BulkValidateIds(ids, dbConnection);
        });
    }

    private bool BulkValidateIds(IEnumerable<int> ids, DBConnection dbConnection)
    ....
}
```